# New level in MultiIndex DataFrame based on existing column level values

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

Let's say I have a DataFrame like this:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(data = [[1,2,3,4,5,6], [3,4,5,6,7,8]], 
                  columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([('A1', 'B1', 'A2'), (10,20)], names=['level_0','level_1']))
```

Here's how it looks like:
[DataFrame image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4LXB.png)

I want to add a **new level** in the columns which contains `1` where `level_0` value contains `"1"` and and `2` where level_0 value contains `"2"`. So, basically:

- Where `level_0 == "A1"` --> `new_level` = `1`
- Where `level_0 == "B1"` --> `new_level` = `1`
- Where `level_0 == "A2"` --> `new_level` = `2`

Any suggestions on how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use lsit comprehension for extract number from first level values and create new MultiIndex by [`MultiIndex.from_tuples`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_tuples.html):

```
import re

df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(re.findall(r'(\d+)$', x[0])[0], *x) 
                                         for x in df.columns.tolist()], 
                                       names=('new_level',*df.columns.names))
print (df)

new_level  1           2   
level_0   A1    B1    A2   
level_1   10 20 10 20 10 20
0          1  2  3  4  5  6
1          3  4  5  6  7  8
```

Comment: Nice, thanks! Can I ask what `*x` is used for?

Comment: @gioarma - it is for unpack tuples, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-asterisk-and-star-asterisk-do-for-parameters)

Answer (score 1):

You could extract the values with a regex (`(\d+)$` = last digits of the value) and rework the MultiIndex with [`MultiIndex.from_arrays`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_arrays.html#pandas.MultiIndex.from_arrays):

```
values = df.columns.get_level_values('level_0').str.extract('(\d+)$', expand=False)
# ['1', '1', '1', '1', '2', '2']

df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([*zip(*df.columns.to_list()), values],
                                       names=[*df.columns.names, 'level_2']
                                      )
```

*NB. this generalizes to any XXX00 value*

output:

```
level_0 A1    B1    A2   
level_1 10 20 10 20 10 20
level_2  1  1  1  1  2  2
0        1  2  3  4  5  6
1        3  4  5  6  7  8
```